# Isomorphism classes of curves $x^{m}+y^{n}=constant$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let us fix two coprime integers $m,n\geq2$ and denote by $K$ the field $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$ of rational functions in one variable over the complex numbers. Consider, for every nonzero constant $c\in K^{\ast}$, the affine curve $\Gamma_{c}$ in $\mathbb{A}^{2}_{K}$ defined by the equation $x^{m}+y^{n}=c$. My question is the following.

Are two such curves $\Gamma_{c}$ and $\Gamma_{c'}$ isomorphic (over $K$) if and only if there exist $a,b\in K$ such that $a^{m}=b^{n}=c/c'$?, i.e. if and only if they are isomorphic via an obvious linear map.

I can prove it in some particular cases and I would highly appreciate any help (proof, hint, counterexample or reference).

Comment: If $m < n/2$ then $y$ (which is a function of degree $m$) is unique up to scalar, by the Castelnuovo genus inequality. Maybe that allows you to conclude in this case. In general, I don't know, but what you are aiming for is uniqueness up to scalar of $x,y$.

Comment: Dear Felipe, thank you very much for your comment. I will try to follow this idea.